# tronWeb getAccount returns null

Tags: node.js, wallet, trx, tronweb

```
(async function () {
    const TronWeb = require('tronweb');

    const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
    const fullNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    const solidityNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    const eventServer = 'https://api.trongrid.io/';
    const privateKey = "04EE63599802B5D31A29C95CC7DF04F427E8F0A124BED9333F3A80404ACFC3127659C540D0162DEDB81AC5F74B2DEB4962656EFE112B252E54AC3BA1207CD1FB1004EE63599802B5D31A29C95CC7DF04F427E8F0A124BED9333F3A80404ACFC3127659C540D0162DEDB81AC5F74B2DEB4962656EFE112B252E54AC3BA1207CD1FB10";
    const  apiKey ='92959baa-2df2-4292-8309-d87ef88a56d6';
    const tronWeb = new TronWeb(fullNode, solidityNode, eventServer, privateKey)
    tronWeb.setHeader({"TRON-PRO-API-KEY": '92959baa-xxx-4292-xxx-d87xxa56d6'});
    
    const newAccount  = await tronWeb.createAccount();
     //return {
          privateKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
          publicKey:      'xxxxxxxxxx',
          address: {
          base58: 'TURYhSKCw3m84MaKmYhoYqd72ULHRn5zJy',
          hex: '41CA6D8549A64DA49324248140789B5A4F52EB022B'
        }
     }

    const account = await tronWeb.trx.getAccount('TURYhSKCw3m84MaKmYhoYqd72ULHRn5zJy');
    console.log(account) // returns  null object {}
})()
```

if i try tronWeb.trx.getAccount function it returns null, i asked CHATGPT it said possible this wallet hasnt any transaction that why it returns null,

but i deposited 5 usdt to  "TX5pWLD2LbaUaF56L4w7Pqwtg2Wp7eKDZ3" this wallet created by  tronWeb.createAccount() when i try request i am getting same action.

uys what is the problem any body can solve this?
i am trying create some wallets TRC20 USDT deposit,transactions etc..

(i used tronweb@4.4 and tronweb@3.2 given same null object result)

Comment: You leaked your API key. You should get it reset immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need the account you have created to be active, this is done by sending some trx, normally 1 trx to activate it and thus be able to consult the information of that account... balance, energy, bandwidth